# Как узнать адрес начала массива в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, c++

Нужно с использованием оператора LEA узнать адрес начала списка символов, чтобы потом с помощью XLAT выбрать нужный символ. С обычной переменной LEA работает, но вот в случае списка ассемблер ругается:

> undefined reference to `table'

Код:

```
using namespace std;
short a,b,c;
int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    char C, *table;
    short d;
    table = new char [16];
    C='0';
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
    table[i]=C;
    cout<<table[i]<<endl;
    C++;
    }
    C='A';
    for (int i=10;i<=15;i++)
    {
    table[i]=C;
    cout<<table[i]<<endl;
    C++;
    }
        __asm__ ("movb $13, %al\n"
        "lea $table, %ebx\n"
        "xlat\n"
        "movb %al, c\n"
        );
    cout << "c= " << table << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: А Вы в чём программируете? В MS VS 2008-2010 следующий код работал 

     int ASCII2Bin(char *buffer, int buffer_len)
     { int i;
       if(buffer_len<=0) return -1;
       _asm
      { ; eDI - VALUE, [eSI] - BUFFER, eBX - MUL10, eCX - длина
          MOV eCX,buffer_len
          MOV eSI,buffer
          CMP eSI,0x2D
          JNZ A4
          INC eSI
          DEC eCX
     A4:
         // ...
      };
      return i;
     }

Т.е. не AT&T синтаксис, а подобие TASM

Comment: Попутал кое-чего, в AT&T синтаксисе вначале идет источник, затем  приемник.

Answer (score 3):

Перед командой `xlat` в регистр `ebx` нужно положить адрес таблицы, вы же пытаетесь положить туда адрес переменной-указателя на таблицу.

Вместо `lea` нужно использовать команду `movl foo, %ebx`, тогда в `ebx` окажется значение переменной (адрес таблицы).

В вашем случае программа отказывается компилироваться, т.к. запись

```
leal $table, %ebx
```

эквивалентна в синтаксисе intel следующей записи:

```
lea ebx, offset table
```

Такой тип операнда-источника `lea` не поддерживает.

Программа скомпилируется, если перед `table` убрать доллар, но результат будет неправильный, т.к., как уже было сказано, в `ebx` окажется адрес переменной-указателя, а не её значение.